# Adding code to __init__.py

Tags: python, initialization, package

I'm taking a look at how the model system in django works and I noticed something that I don't understand.

I know that you create an empty `__init__.py` file to specify that the current directory is a package.  And that you can set some variable in `__init__.py` so that import * works properly.

But django adds a bunch of from ... import ... statements and defines a bunch of classes in `__init__.py`.  Why?  Doesn't this just make things look messy?  Is there a reason that requires this code in `__init__.py`?

Comment: This isn't really about Django is it?  Yes, you saw it first in Django, but this seems more like a pure Python thing -- maybe the Django tag isn't really appropriate.

Comment: I don't see any import statements in `__init__.py` django 1.8. Was this for an older version? if so which version?

Comment: Thanks for this question, it's pretty hard to find any advice on the real pros and cons of defining code in `__init__.py`. Unfortunately I still haven't found any solid answers on what can go wrong or what's best practice with putting code in `__init__.py`.  One answer below suggested it's historical and a re-write would do it differently. I think that's my only take-away.

Comment: This question also has some relevant discussion: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1944569/how-do-i-write-good-correct-package-init-py-files

Comment: some https://blog.pcarleton.com/post/python-init/
articles https://www.codingem.com/what-is-init-py-file-in-python/
on __init__.py https://realpython.com/lessons/package-initialization/

Answer (score 82, accepted):

All imports in `__init__.py` are made available when you import the package (directory) that contains it.

Example:

`./dir/__init__.py`:

```
import something
```

`./test.py`:

```
import dir
# can now use dir.something
```

EDIT: forgot to mention, the code in `__init__.py` runs the first time you import any module from that directory. So it's normally a good place to put any package-level initialisation code.

EDIT2: dgrant pointed out to a possible confusion in my example. In `__init__.py` `import something` can import any module, not necessary from the package. For example, we can replace it with `import datetime`, then in our top level `test.py` both of these snippets will work:

```
import dir
print dir.datetime.datetime.now()
```

and

```
import dir.some_module_in_dir
print dir.datetime.datetime.now()
```

The bottom line is: all names assigned in `__init__.py`, be it imported modules, functions or classes, are automatically available in the package namespace whenever you import the package or a module in the package.

Comment: Okay, thanks.  But I'm still not sure why it would be a good idea to add classes to `__init__.py`  I don't really consider these classes initialization code (but maybe I'm wrong about that).

Comment: These are probably the classes that are useful each time you work with the package. But I don't want to speculate, there could be many reasons why they are there, objective or not :)

Comment: This can also be for historical reasons. When you are converting module to package, module.py to module/__init__.py all existing code can use it as before but now module can have submodules.

Comment: Modules execute parent `__init__.py` implicitly. By importing the modules inside `__init__.py`, you are creating cyclic imports. The `__init__.py` will not be executed fully before one such import.
It is safer to keep `__init__.py` empty.

Comment: It's important to remark that this is nothing specific to `__init__.py` files. If you had a file `dir/other.py` which had something like `from datetime import datetime` you would also be able to call `dir.other.datetime.now()` or even `from dir.other import datetime`.

Answer (score 44):

It's just personal preference really, and has to do with the layout of your python modules.

Let's say you have a module called `erikutils`. There are two ways that it can be a module, either you have a file called *erikutils.py* on your `sys.path` or you have a directory called *erikutils* on your `sys.path` with an empty *`__init__.py`* file inside it. Then let's say you have a bunch of modules called `fileutils`, `procutils`, `parseutils` and you want those to be sub-modules under `erikutils`. So you make some .py files called *fileutils.py*, *procutils.py*, and *parseutils.py*:

```
erikutils
  __init__.py
  fileutils.py
  procutils.py
  parseutils.py
```

Maybe you have a few functions that just don't belong in the `fileutils`, `procutils`, or `parseutils` modules. And let's say you don't feel like creating a new module called `miscutils`. AND, you'd like to be able to call the function like so:

```
erikutils.foo()
erikutils.bar()
```

rather than doing

```
erikutils.miscutils.foo()
erikutils.miscutils.bar()
```

So because the `erikutils` module is a directory, not a file, we have to define it's functions inside the *`__init__.py`* file.

In django, the best example I can think of is `django.db.models.fields`. ALL the django *Field classes are defined in the *`__init__.py`* file in the *django/db/models/fields* directory. I guess they did this because they didn't want to cram everything into a hypothetical *django/db/models/fields.py* model, so they split it out into a few submodules (*related.py*, *files.py*, for example) and they stuck the made *Field definitions in the fields module itself (hence, *`__init__.py`*).

Comment: dgrant, what I meant is that `something` can be an external module, dir.something will sill work. Thanks for the comment, I will edit my post to make it more clear.

Comment: Do you know if this has been changed on python 3.10? i.e. I used to kept "miscutils" in `__init__.py` and call `erikutils.foo()` on python 3.8 but seems like I have to call `erikutils.__init__.foo()` on python 3.10.

Answer (score 30):

Using the `__init__.py` file allows you to make the internal package structure invisible from the outside. If the internal structure changes (e.g. because you split one fat module into two) you only have to adjust the `__init__.py` file, but not the code that depends on the package. You can also make parts of your package invisible, e.g. if they are not ready for general usage.

Note that you can use the `del` command, so a typical `__init__.py` may look like this:

```
from somemodule import some_function1, some_function2, SomeObject

del somemodule
```

Now if you decide to split `somemodule` the new `__init__.py` might be:

```
from somemodule1 import some_function1, some_function2
from somemodule2 import SomeObject

del somemodule1
del somemodule2
```

From the outside the package still looks exactly as before.

Comment: @Arlen: The point is that it is not part of the public API. If you rename a module you can be sure that no dependent code breaks. In addition this ensures that the API elements only appear once, e.g., when introspection is used to automatically create API documentation.

Comment: @Arlen: Deleting a module prevents one from `import <pack>.somemodule1` directly. You can only import from `<pack>` objects defined or imported in its `__init__.py`, and non-deleted submodules.

Comment: Good point pointing out the `del` option. Something to bear in mind if you want to clean up the namespace, although if you're doing so much in `__init__.py` that you have to clean up afterwards makes me thing you need another sub-module.

Answer (score 7):

> "We recommend not putting much code in an `__init__.py` file, though. Programmers do not expect actual logic to happen in this file, and much like with `from x import *`, it can trip them up if they are looking for the declaration of a particular piece of code and can't find it until they check `__init__.py`. "
>
> -- Python Object-Oriented Programming Fourth Edition Steven F. Lott Dusty Phillips