# Calling modules from different packages in a python Project

Tags: python

I am trying to wrap my head around the use of the `__init__` file in python and I though I did it correctly but I am getting a "No module named ..." error.

I put the project here [link to project](https://github.com/spitfiredd/pythonds) for simplicity.  The issue in question is `pythonds/test/parens.py`, I have `__init__.py` files in all my directories so I am not sure where I have gone wrong with this.

I have also tried using [PEP 238](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0328/) using `from ..basic.stack import Stack` and get the error

```
ValueError: Attempted relative import in non-package
```

I though all I had to do was stick an `__init__.py` files into my directories to make them a module and then I would be able to call them from different modules.

Answer (score 1):

Within the `__init__.py` file, put:

```
from myfile import *
```

for instance:

```
pythonds/test/parens.py
pythonds/test/__init__.py
```

Where the `__init__.py` would contain:

```
from parens import *
```

That's the dirty quick-fix version for older python versions.
Considering you have multiple subdirectories something along the lines of (see blow) would be better for all python versions:

In your `__init__.py` in the folder **test** place:

```
__all__ = ['tacos','falaffels']
from test.tacos import factory
from test.falaffels import stand
```

If you have the following folder structure the above should work:

```
main.py
/test/
    __init__.py
    tacos.py
    falaffels.py
```

Also just noticed that this might be a duplicate of: [How do I write good/correct package __init__.py files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1944569/how-do-i-write-good-correct-init-py-files)

Answer (score 0):

Annoyingly, you elide the actual error: no module named *what*? If, as I suspect, it says "no module named 'pythonds', then the problem has nothing to do with `__init__.py` at all. It is simply that the base `pythonds` directory is not on your Python path, presumably because you're running the test from within its own directory.

Python automatically puts the *current* directory in its path: so if ran the test from the `pythonds` directory you would be able to do `from basic.stack import Stack`. Otherwise, you could add the full path to the directory *above* `parends` to `sys.path`.

A couple of other tips: you probably already know that the `collections` module already defines a deque class, and lists can be easily used as stacks already. But more to the point, note that it's not necessary in Python to define a separate file for each class: all three could live in the same `stack.py` file.

Also, your tests aren't really tests. You should look into the `unittest` module for how to write proper unit tests in Python.