# Is it pythonic to use __init__.py modules of a package for generic, abstract classes?

Tags: python, python-3.x, abstract-class, declaration

I am developing a rather complex application for my company following the object-oriented model in python3. The application contains several packages and sub-packages, each - of course - containing an __init__.py module.

I mostly used those __init__.py modules to declare generic classes for the package inside them, which are intended to be used as abstract templates for their respective package only.

My question is now: Is this a "nice" / "correct" / "pythonic" way to use the __init__.py module(s)? Or shall I rather declare my generic classes somewhere else?

To give an example, let's assume a package `mypkg`:

`mypkg.__init__.py`:

```
class Foo(object):
    __some_attr = None

    def __init__(self, some_attr):
        self.__some_attr = some_attr

    @property
    def some_attr(self):
        return self.__some_attr

    @some_attr.setter
    def some_attr(self, val):
        self.__some_attr = val
```

`mypkg.myfoo.py`:

```
from . import Foo

class MyFoo(Foo):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__("this is my implemented value")

    def printme(self):
        print(self.some_attr)
```

Comment: Is your current approach causing any headaches? Changing something which is working fine because somebody might consider it unpythonic is unpythonic.

Comment: I always thought of `__init__.py`, if used for anything at all, to be for module initialization (such as creating any module-wide state objects, etc) and for presenting the public interface of the module.  Another way to think about it, I think, is that `__init__.py` performs the analogous role for the module object created when the module is imported as the `__init__()` method of a class performs for a newly created instance of that class.

Comment: @timgeb There is no technical or conceptional problem whatsoever. The application works just fine. Nonetheless I am new to python and now want to tidy up stuff, to make it follow the PEPs.
@SilasRay So what's your proposal then? Shall I put the abstract classes in some module `abstract.py ` or `templates.py`?

Comment: My personal opinion: it would be the last place I would look for something like that, so assuming I'm not alone, you're probably going to confuse other people who read your code. I don't think that's Pythonic.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It depends by what is the API you want to provide. For example the [`collections`](http://hg.python.org/cpython/file/abcf17bc5eae/Lib/collections/__init__.py) module in the standard library defines all the classes in the `__init__.py`<sup>1</sup>.
And the standard library should be pretty "pythonic", whatever that means.

*However* it provides mostly a "module-like" interface. It's quite rare to see:

```
import collections.abc
```

If you already have subpackages you are probably better introducing a new subpackage.
If, currently, the use of the package doesn't actually depend on subpackages you might consider putting the code in the `__init__.py`. Or put the code in some private module and simply import the names inside `__init__.py` (this is what *I*'d prefer)

---

If you are only concerned with where it's better to put the Abstract Base Classes, as shown above (`collections.abc` contains the abstract base classes of the `collections` package), and as you can see from the standard library's [`abc`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/abc.html) module, it's common to define an `abc.py` submodule that contains them.
You may consider exposing them directly from the `__init__.py` doing:

```
from .abc import *
from . import abc

# ...
__all__ = list_of_names_to_export + abc.__all__
```

inside your `__init__.py`.

---

<sup>1</sup> The actual implementation used is in C however: [`_collectionsmodule.c`](http://hg.python.org/cpython/file/abcf17bc5eae/Modules/_collectionsmodule.c)

Comment: An .abc package seems to be a fitting solution for my purposes. Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

You can always put *everything* into one source file. The reason for splitting the more complex code into separate modules or packages is to separate the things that are mutually related from things that are unrelated. The separated things should be as independent as possible on the rest. And it applies to any level: data structures, functions, classes, modules, packages, applications.

Inside the module or inside the package should apply the same rules. I agree with [Bakuriu](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24269327/1346705) that `__init__.py` should be closely related to the package infrastructure, but not neccessarily to the functionality of the module. My personal opinion is that the `__init__.py` should be as simple as possible. The reason firstly is that *everything should be as simple as possible but not simpler*. Secondly, people reading the code of your package tend to think that way. They may not expect the unexpected functionality in `__init__.py`. It would probably be better to create `generic.py` inside the package for the purpose. It is easier to document the purpose of the module (say via its top docstring).

The better the separation is from the beginning, the better can the independent features be combined in future. You get better flexibility -- both for the usage of module inside the package and also for future modifications.

Answer (score 0):

It is indeed possible to use `__init__.py` for a specific module initialization, but I have never seen someone using it to define new functions. The only "correct" use I know is what is discussed in [this subject ...](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1944569/how-do-i-write-good-correct-package-init-py-files).

Anyway, as you might have a complex application, you can use a temporary file where you define all your needed functions instead of defining them directly in `__init__.py` module. This will allow you more readability it is easier to change afterwards.

Comment: What do you mean by _temporary_ _file_?
I am not defining raw functions in `__init__.py`.
I am defining generic _classes_ there to be extended by other classes in the respective packages' sub-packages and modules.

Answer (score 0):

Don't **ever** use `__init__.py` for anything except to define `__all__`. You will save so many lives if you will avoid it.

**Reason**: It is common for developers to look at packages and modules. But there is a problem you can stuck with sometimes. If you have package, you assume that there is a modules and code inside of it. But you will rarely count `__init__.py` as one, because, let's face it, most times it is just a requirement to make modules from directory importable.

```
package
    __init__.py
    mod1.py
    humans.py
    cats.py
    dogs.py
    cars.py
    commons.py
```

Where should be located class `Family`? It is common class and it depends on others, because we can create family of humans, dogs and cats, even cars!

By my logic, and logic of my friends, it should be places in separated file, but I will try to find it in `commons`, next in `humans` and then... I will be embarrassed, because I don't really know where it is!

Stupid example, huh? But it gives a point.

Comment: There are **many** more *completely* legit usages. Two simple examples: loading modules that are OS specific. Providing commonly used objects that are definined in submodules.

Comment: Yea, this is what I mean "defining `__all__`" - just loading and providing modules.