# Is this an okay way of doing Django Models

Tags: python, django, django-models

I am doing the [*fat models*](http://redbeacon.github.io/2014/01/28/Fat-Models-a-Django-Code-Organization-Strategy/) approach, so I have transformed my models.py into a package thus:

```
+--polls/
|  +--models/
|    +--__init__.py
|    +--__shared_imports.py
|    +--Choice.py
|    +--Question.py
```

My **main part of the question** is the `__shared_imports.py`: I realized that we've common import statements in various modules in the package and decided to to have that file to do the imports, then in my modules I write this:

```py
from __shared_imports.py import *
```

Everything works fine, but just want to know if this approach is good. I'll appreciate your thoughts on this.

Comment: Forget about the naming of my `__shared_imports.py`, I can have that changed, my main question is around the **approach**. Thanks @volodymr for raising that.

Comment: What exactly is in the `__shared_imports.py`? Is it just importing things from elsewhere?

Comment: Yes, other than having to redo the same import statements in my modules, since in normal `models.py` we will have all the imports in one place. Does that make sense? @shuttle87

Then I leave the rest of specific imports that are not shared for the respective modules in the package.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

avoid `import  *` because it will prevent tools like pyflakes from determining undefined variables.

to move all of it in a subdirectory and splitting it into separate files is not a bad idea, albeit mostly not needed. when your models.py file gets big, you should rather be thinking about splitting the project up into smaller apps.

Answer (score 2):

1. Use only lower case when you name modules.
2. Do not use double underscore for module name.
3. Read PEP8 and Google Python style guide.
4. Use less verbose names for modules. For example: shared_imports.py -> shared.py

Got it.

In this case you need to import everything in `__init__.py`.
Then you can export all names as `__all__ = ['Choice', 'Question']`

So, it will be enough just to import models package.

Example: __ init __.py

```
import Choice
import Question

__all__ = ['Choice', 'Question']
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer @volodymyr, however my main question isn't around the naming, I can have that changed -- but the approach.

Comment: __ init __.py
...
import Choice
import Question

__all__ = ['Choice', 'Question']

Comment: [This](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1944569/how-do-i-write-good-correct-package-init-py-files) is not my concern...