# Python packaging: subdirectories not installed

Tags: python, setuptools, packaging, setup.py

I have a Python project with the layout

```
setup.py
foobar/
    __init__.py
    foo.py
    bar/
        __init__.py
```

Where the `foobar/__init__.py` reads

```
from . import foo
from . import bar
```

and `setup.py`

```
from setuptools import setup

setup(
    name='foobar',
    version='0.0.1',
    packages=['foobar'],
    )
```

When doing `import foobar` from the source directory, it all works as expected. However, when installing the package via `pip install .`, the subfolder `bar/` is *not* installed, leading to the import error

```
ImportError: cannot import name bar
```

Any hints?

Comment: i think bar is a folder not python file(.py)

Comment: That's right. Why does this impair the installation though?

Comment: try this link for __init__.py http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1944569/how-do-i-write-good-correct-package-init-py-files

Answer (score 27, accepted):

Apparently to include subpackages, you need `find_packages()`:

```
from setuptools import setup, find_packages

setup(
    name='foobar',
    version='0.0.1',
    packages=find_packages()
    )
```

This is recommended​ in [the setuptools docs](https://setuptools.readthedocs.io/en/latest/setuptools.html#using-find-packages) as well.

Comment: Exact Link: https://setuptools.readthedocs.io/en/latest/setuptools.html#using-find-packages

Comment: find_packages() installs the subdirectory, but the import still fails.

Comment: Same here, the subdirectories are installed, but cannot import. Found an answer to this at some point?