# How python modules are imported?

Tags: python, python-2.7, import, module

Python version: **2.7.12**

I created my own module which is called `mymodule.py`. I put the module inside the `mymodule` directory, so:

```
mymodule/
  __init__.py
  mymodule.py
```

Additionally I checked the `sys.path` list and I moved whole `mymodule/` to `/usr/lib64/python2.7/site-packages/` where the `numpy/` catalog is also located. When I run the python I can import `mymodule` in all these ways:

```
>>> import mymodule.mymodule
>>> from mymodule import mymodule
>>> from mymodule.mymodule import fun1, var1
```

I understand the hierarchy of files and catalogs. I know that `mymodule/` is level up than `mymodule`, thus a dot operator is needed. But we can notice similar structure for the `numpy/` catalog and in this case:

```
>>> import numpy
```

is enough to import this module, not:

```
>>> import numpy.numpy
```

I read the official documentation about modules and I can't find the answer. Of course I can put `mymodule.py` inside `/usr/lib64/python2.7/site-packages/` but it could cause a mess. Moreover `mymodule/` give me something like a namespace (someone else can create also `mymodule.py` file containing different statements).

Which way is recommended to publish own modules?

Comment: Here's an exercise. Go to the `numpy` package. Open the top level `__init__.py` file and look at what's in there. ;)

Comment: Ah, screw it. Here it is: https://github.com/qsnake/numpy/blob/master/numpy/__init__.py

Comment: Does this Q/A help https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1944569/how-do-i-write-good-correct-package-init-py-files