# Errors while running DeepMind's publicly available code regarding their recent mathematical breakthrough

Tags: python, module, large-language-model

I am trying to re-produce DeepMind's recent result, in which they found new examples of mathematical objects using LLM's.

I am trying to execute their [publicly available code on GitHub](https://github.com/google-deepmind/funsearch/tree/main/implementation). However, despite running all of the code in the "implementation" folder, I keep getting the error "no module named funsearch found". Note that the file named "funsearch" gives the same error.

Why is that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, so take a look at this two links
[adding a init file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54333865/python-no-module-named-error-package-is-not-a-package) and [what to put on the init file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67100775/how-to-write-python-init-py-file-for-module)

I added $__init__.py$ files to their folders, and to use the dot notation I wrote
`from .implementation import *` on the init file of the folder funsearch.

From outside of the folder funsearch I can do:

`from funsearch.implementation import programs_database_test as test`
and it gives me no problem.

Also, I renamed the funsearch.py file to fun_search.py (but this may not be necessary).

Comment: Thanks! Another thing that worked for me was removing the "from funsearch.implementation" commands.

Comment: Did you also try to run the whole code, in the sense that did you put in a shoddy code, and then have it evolve into better code?

Comment: If you go to the repository and click on the issues you will find an implementation here [Implementation](https://github.com/jonppe/funsearch), however, it has some changes with respect to the original implementation.