# ModuleNotFoundError: No module named, but file nested within module

Tags: python, module, nested

I have a query over modules in Python.

Using VSCode I have the following simple code set up:

```
Demo/
    Test.py
    z1/
        \_\_init\_\_.py
        Foo.py
        z2/
            \_\_init\_\_.py
            Screen.py
```

screen.py contains:

```
class Screen:
SCREEN_SIZE = [800, 600]
```

and z2/__init__.py

```
from  z1.z2.Screen import *
```

and both the following Foo.py and Test.py have:

```
from z1.z2.Screen import *
print(Screen.SCREEN_SIZE)
```

why is it when I run Test.py, I get:

```
[800, 600]
```

But when I run Foo.py, I get:

```
File "***\Python\z1\Foo.py", line 1, in <module>
    from z1.z2 import *
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'z1'
```

I can changed the z1.z2 in the __init__.py to just z2, but then Test.py doesn't work.
Is there any means to have it work for both files?

Comment: I believe the issue was how I set up the environment, and that the project directory was not added to PYTHONPATH, which is why the absolute import was not working.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It appears you are not using a virtual environment, which causes the files to run sort-of independently.

As is, you are trying to import `z1` inside `Foo.py`, but `Foo.py` only sees a sub-folder named `z2`. Changing the import statement in `Foo.py` to `from z2.Screen import *` fixes the issue for the time being.

If using a virtual environment, then you'd have to use `import` as if the file is located in the main directory.

As a side-note,  [this might give some better insight to using `_init_.py`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1944569/how-do-i-write-good-correct-package-init-py-files)

Comment: So if I make the interpreter look in my Demo folder for all the modules, it should then work? Is there not a way to make sure VSCode always treats the project folder as the place to search for packages/modules, otherwise you couldn't use absolute paths anywhere but files in the main project folder

Comment: I was trying to use absolute import from the project folder, which I have fixed by adding to the PYTHONPATH.

Answer (score 0):

I personally do not like Pythons import system. When running Foo.py are you able to import use `from z2.Screen import *` successfully?

I have (unfortunately) used the following to work for test code as well

```
try:
    from x.y import z
except ImportError:
    from y import z
```

But I guess you could use [os.path](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.path.html) to add root path to Foo.py as well. In Foo.py you could try adding

```
import sys

sys.path.append('../')
```