# Why shouldn't I use __init__.py to separate public from private classes?

Tags: python, import, package, private, public

I am implementing a benchmark. In a subpackage, I have implemented a workload setup. To make the code easier accessible, I want to split the code into public and private classes.

```
benchmark/
- __init__.py
- benchmark.py -> Benchmark
- workload/
  - __init__.py
  - loader.py -> WorkloadLoader
  - validation.py -> WorkloadValidation
  - internal_logic1.py -> Internal1
  - internal_logic2.py -> Internal2
```

I see three options:

1. Prefix the internal classes with an underscore (e.g., `_Internal1`). This has the disadvantage that it will add even more underscores in the code. (For me, underscore prefixes work better with snake case methods than camel case classes.)
2. Move all internal classes to a new subpackage `benchmark.workload.internal`. This has the disadvantage, that it creates deeper folder hierarchies.
3. Only import the classes that are public in the `__init__.py` file of the `workload` package. In theory, you would need another step to look up code, but in practice IDEs like Intellij will do the work for you.

Of the three options, option 3 is the best choice in my eyes. It has the additional advantage, that it reduces the import paths:

```
# from
from workload.loader import WorkloadLoader
from workload.validation import WorkloadValidation

# to
from workload import WorkloadLoader, WorkloadValidation
```

This looks like a clean module boundary. Yet, answers from another SO posts seem to disagree: [How do I write good/correct package __init__.py files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1944569/how-do-i-write-good-correct-package-init-py-files)

**Question** Why I should not use `__init__.py` to separate public from private classes?

**Example**

```
# workload/__init__.py:
from .loader import WorkloadLoader
from .validation import WorkloadValidation
```

Comment: what do you mean by 'private classes' ?

Comment: Classes that I don't consider part of the package's public interface and thus don't want to expose. Similar to private classes in Java.

Comment: 'similar to Java', I don't know any Java, so that does not explain it. 'Private' does not exist in Python. I agree that your imports look cleaner, and "flat is better then nested"; if there are only a few files, I would keep it in 1 folder, once it gets bigger, make it easier to import by defining `__all__` in __init__