# different import results at different directories

Tags: python

I have a package MyPak and a module MyMod. The files are organized in the following way:

> somedir/MyPak/MyMod.py

in MyMod.py there is only a Class whose name is also MyMod

in directory **somedir/MyPak**, if I do the import:

```
import MyMod
```

I got MyMod imported as a Module.

But in directory **somedir/**, if I do

```
from MyPak import MyMod
```

I got MyMod imported as a Class, not a Module. Why is this the case?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This behavior is indicative that you have a file:

```
somedir/MyPak/__init__.py
```

wherein you do the following:

```
from MyMod import *
```

When you `import MyPak`, it imports from that `__init__.py` - likewise, when you `from MyPak import something`, it's going to try to pull from the namespace for the package - which will look inside that `__init__.py`

Because you imported everything from `MyMod` inside `__init__.py`, now the class is local to the `MyPak` package, and masks the `MyMod.py` file.

Comment: That's true. I did find the file \__init\__.py which contains `from MyMod import MyMod`. But which masks which? I thought \__init\__.py is first executed (MyMod because a class) and then the `import MyMod` part from the code `from MyPak import MyMod` is executed (this masks the previous result and makes MyMod a module again.

Comment: Forgot to say thanks :)
How about other modules in the directory somedir/MyPak ? Because I see also `from MyMod2 import MyMod2`; `from MyMod3 import MyMod3` and so on in the file \__init\__.py. If somedir/MyPak/\__init\__.py is executed when I do `from MyPak import MyMod`, then where have MyMod2, MyMod3, etc been imported?

Comment: **re your first comment**: Nope.  The line `from MyPak import MyMod` will first attempt to import the `MyMod` symbol from `MyPak/__init__.py`'s namespace, and only failing that will it attempt to import some file `MyPak/MyMod.py`.  Because you **have** imported that symbol into `MyPak`'s namespace, it will be imported directly from there.

Comment: **re your 2nd comment**: They were not imported :^(  You need to either import each specifically, *OR*, just `import MyPak` (or `from MyPak import *`, which gets everything). ALTERNATIVELY, you can say `from MyPak.MyMod import MyMod`, and cut out the middleman!

Comment: I don't quite understand the part that " ... attempt to import the MyMod symbol from MyPak/__init__.py's namespace" but the rest lines in MyPak/\_\_init\_\_.py are not executed. Could you point me to some further documents explaining this issue?

Comment: I want to import MyMod as **module** particularly because I want to make some changes to the code MyMod.py and test the changes in python shell by reloading the module. But if it is imported as a Class, how should I reload it without restarting Python shell? (perhaps I should ask it in a new question :)

Comment: [here's a link regarding package namespace and `__init__.py`](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/119167/adding-code-to-init-py).  And I encourage you to ask a new question, as this is quite a discussion here in the comments.