# How can you update a pyfile in the middle of a PySpark shell session?

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark

Within an interactive pyspark session you can import python files via `sc.addPyFile('file_location')`.  If you need to make changes to that file and save them, is there any way to "re-broadcast" the updated file without having to shut down your spark session and start a new one?

Simply adding the file again doesn't work.  I'm not sure if renaming the file works, but I don't want to do that anyways.

As far as I can tell from the spark documentation there is only a method to add a pyfile, not update one.  I'm hoping that I missed something!

Thanks

Comment: I haven't tested this, but could you just follow http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6946376/how-to-reload-a-class-in-python-shell within your pyspark-shell?

Comment: Have you tried setting spark.files.overwrite to true in your spark-defaults.conf? http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/configuration.html

Comment: Hmm i have not tried either of those.  sparknoob yours sounds like it's exactly what I'm looking for so I'll try that first and get back to you.  Thanks.

Comment: Nope, unfortunately those don't work for me.  I tried both sc.addFile and sc.addPyFile, and neither of them seem to actually be overwriting the files with my changes mid-session.  Any other possible solutions?

Comment: Check out https://stackoverflow.com/a/44387776/1843329, although it sounds like that solution isn't reliable in practice.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think it's feasible during an interactive session. You will have to restart your session to use the modified module.

Comment: how do you restart a session in the middle of an interactice session?