# PySpark Overwrite added sc.addPyFile

Tags: python-3.x, apache-spark, pyspark

I have these 2 files saved under this path:

C:\code\sample1\main.py

```
def method():
    return "this is sample method 1"
```

C:\code\sample2\main.py

```
def method():
    return "this is sample method 2"
```

and then i run this:

```
from pyspark import SparkContext
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession

sc = SparkContext()
spark = SparkSession(sc)

sc.addPyFile("~/code/sample1/main.py")
main1 = __import__("main")
print(main1.method()) # this is sample method 1

sc.addPyFile("~/code/sample2/main.py") # Error
```

The error is

Py4JJavaError: An error occurred while calling o21.addFile.
: org.apache.spark.SparkException: File C:\Users\hans.yulian\AppData\Local\Temp\spark-5da165cf-410f-4576-8124-0ab23aba6aa3\userFiles-25a7ca23-84fb-42b7-95d9-206867fb9dfd\main.py exists and does not match contents of /C:/Users/hans.yulian/Documents/spark-test/main2/main.py

Which means that it already have "main.py" file in their temporary folder and the content is different. I wonder if there are any workaround for this case, but for me i have these limitation:

1. The file name still have to be "main.py", only folder can be
   different
2. It's okay to somehow purge the temporary folder to add aga
3. in another file The only solution i have is by appending random
   string in front of main.py, for example **abcdemain.py** and
   **fghijmain.py**, then i will import main =  __import__("abcdemain"),
   but this one is not really preferable

Answer (score 7):

While it is technically possible, by setting `spark.files.overwrite`  to `"true"`:

```
from pyspark import SparkConf, SparkContext

sc = SparkContext(conf=SparkConf().set("spark.files.overwrite", "true"))
```

and in simple cases will give correct results

```
def f(*_):                                                                   
    from main import method
    return [method()]

sc.addFile("/path/to/sample1/main.py") 
sc.parallelize([], 3).mapPartitions(f).collect()
```

```
['this is sample method 1',
'this is sample method 1',
'this is sample method 1']
```

```py
sc.addFile("/path/to/sample2/main.py")

sc.parallelize([], 3).mapPartitions(f).collect()
```

```
['this is sample method 2',
 'this is sample method 2',
 'this is sample method 2']
```

**it won't be reliable in practice**, even if you [`reload`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/importlib.html?highlight=reload#importlib.reload) modules on each access and will make your application hard to reason about. Since Spark may implicitly cache certain objects, or transparently restart Python workers you can easily end up in a situation, where different nodes see different state of the source.

Answer (score 0):

I think this is b/c, perhaps, it will add all those files into an ultimately flat directory structure?  So indeed, it is trying to overwrite, or shove 2 things into the same directory with the same name.  Try to rename them and see what happens.