# documentations about how __init__.py works?

Tags: python

I stumbled over the import of __init__.py in python packages. See posts:

- [different import results at different directories](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6945592/different-import-results-at-different-directories)
- [how to reload a Class in python shell?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6946376/how-to-reload-a-class-in-python-shell)

I was directed by Nate to very good explanations at this post:

[Adding code to __init__.py](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/119167/adding-code-to-init-py).

I want to read more about this topic and more related topics. Could anyone suggest further formal documentations or books on the topics? TIA!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a very good explanation at:

http://effbot.org/zone/import-confusion.htm#what-does-python-do

and the critical sentence for me was:

> When Python imports a module, it first checks the module registry
>   (**`sys.modules`**) to see if the module is already imported. If that’s the
>   case, Python uses the existing module object as is.

Answer (score 2):

Start here:

Python provides some acceptable tutorials which lead you to a basic understanding how the concepts of the language work.

This http://docs.python.org/tutorial/modules.html describes how modules *and* their initializers work.

In addition to that - if you want it the most formal way and can't get along with the language documentation for some reason - look in the PEPs (e.g. [PEP 273](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0273/) dealing with module imports from zip files)