# Best practice for handling path/executables in project scripts in Python (e.g. something like Django's manage.py, or fabric)

Tags: python, fabric

I do a lot of work on different projects (I'm a scientist) in a fairly standardised directory structure. e.g.:

```
project
   /analyses/
   /lib
   /doc
   /results
   /bin
```

I put all my various utility scripts in /bin/ because cleanliness is next to godliness. However, I have to hard code paths (e.g. ../../x/y/z) and then I have to run things within ./bin/ or they break.

I've used Django and that has /manage.py which runs various django-things and automatically handles the path. I've also used fabric to run various user defined functions.

Question: How do I do something similar? and what's the best way? I can easily write something in /manage.py to inject the root dir into sys.path etc, but then I'd like to be able to do "./manage.py foo" which would run /bin/foo.py. Or is it possible to get fabric to call executables from a certain directory?

Basically - I want something easy and low maintenance. I want to be able to drop an executable script/file/whatever into ./bin/ and not have to deal with path issues or import issues.

What is the best way to do this?

Comment: I would just emulate what django is doing https://github.com/django/django/blob/master/django/core/management/__init__.py, with it's manage.py

Comment: @dm03514 Saying "emulate this" and linking to a 400 line file is too opaque for me. I don't understand which aspects of it you're suggesting are worth emulation.

Answer (score 6):

#### Keep Execution at TLD

In general, try to keep your runtime at top-level.  This will straighten out your imports tremendously.

If you have to do a lot of import addressing with relative imports, there's probably a 
better way.

#### Modifying The Path

Other poster's have mentioned the `PYTHONPATH`.  That's a great way to do it permanently in your shell.

If you don't want to/aren't able to manipulate the `PYTHONPATH` project path directly you can use `sys.path` to get yourself out of relative import hell.

#### Using `sys.path.append`

`sys.path` is just a list internally.  You can append to it to add stuff to into your path.

Say I'm in `/bin` and there's a library `markdown` in `lib/`.  You can append a relative paths with `sys.path` to import what you want.

```
import sys
sys.path.append('../lib')
import markdown


print markdown.markdown("""

Hello world!
------------

""")
```

**Word to the wise:** Don't get too crazy with your sys.path additions.  Keep your schema simple to avoid yourself a lot confusion.

Overly eager imports can sometimes lead to cases where a python module needs to import itself, at which point execution will halt!

#### Using Packages and `__init__.py`

Another great trick is creating python packages by adding `__init__.py` files.  `__init__.py` gets loaded before any other modules in the directory, so it's a great way to add imports across the entire directory.  This makes it an ideal spot to add `sys.path` hackery.

You don't even need to necessarily add anything to the file.  It's sufficient to just do `touch __init__.py` at the console to make a directory a package.

[See this SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/119178/133414) for a more concrete example.

Answer (score 4):

In a shell script that you source (not run) in your current shell you set the following environment variables:

```
PATH=$PATH:$PROJECTDIR/bin
PYTHONPATH=$PROJECTDIR/lib
```

Then you put your Python modules and package tree in your projects ./lib directory. Python automatically adds the PYTHONPATH environment variable to `sys.path`.

Then you can run any top-level script from the shell without specifying the path, and any imports from your library modules are looked for in the lib directory.

I recommend very simple top-level scripts, such as:

```
#!/usr/bin/python

import sys
import mytool

mytool.main(sys.argv)
```

Then you never have to change that, you just edit the module code, and also benefit from the byte-code caching.

Comment: You're a lifesaver. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You can easily achieve your goals by creating a mini package that hosts each one of your projects. Use [paste scripts](http://lucasmanual.com/mywiki/PythonPaste) to create a simple project skeleton. And to make it executable, just install it via `setup.py develop`. Now your bin scripts just need to import the entry point to this package and execute it.

Comment: Sometimes, a package for every executable script seems heavyweight. My biggest project at work has dozens of executable scripts, which currently reside in a single dir within a larger project of source files. Turning all of these into packages seems more work/complexity that ought to be needed. Am I being foolish?