# Run and execute another python script in existing python script executed

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter

I'm using **python version 3.4.2**.

I have two python script **with tkinter used**.

Example: `one.py` and `two.py`.
Then in two.py, there will be a back button, thus when the back button is clicked, it will close the two.py and back to one.py.

This is my elif statement in one.py:

```
elif len(admin) == 1 and len(staff) == 0:
----open and run two.py----
```

In two.py:

```
def back():
   app.destroy()

back = Button(command=back).pack()
```

Is there any way i can get this going? Thank you.

Comment: So you want to run `one.py` and `two.py` as separate programs?

Comment: @J.P.Petersen yes. it's like a front end and back end program

Answer (score 0):

What you want to do is import your `back()` function from your python file `two.py`. This works like so:

In your one.py, write:

```
import two
...  # remaining imports
# ...
elif len(admin) == 1 and len(staff) == 0:
    back = Button(commmand=two.back).pack()
```

Read up on [what importing is and how it works here](https://www.codementor.io/sheena/tutorials/python-path-virtualenv-import-for-beginners-du107r3o1).

Answer (score 0):

You need to pass `app` as parent to `back` button:

**Example:**

```
class app(Toplevel):
    def __init__(self, parent, *args, **kwargs):
        Toplevel.__init__(self, parent, *args, **kwargs)
        Button(self, command=self.destroy).pack()
```

Answer (score 0):

consider to modularize your application. modularization is [pacesetter](https://english.stackexchange.com/a/175615) among other available options.

create an `__init__.py` in your project folder, where one.py and two.py is located ([more about](https://stackoverflow.com/a/119178/4481312) `__init__.py`).

one.py

```
import random
x = random.randint(1,5)

if x>3:
    from two import foo
    print foo(x)
else:
    print x
```

two.py

```
def foo(x):
    return "fooed:", x,
```

run

```
$ python one.py 
('fooed:', 5)
$ python one.py 
1
```